# Listview crashes app when trying to change item backgroung color

Tags: android, listview

I am facing a problem that I understand but can not find a solution to.So - I have a listview and some items in it.I want to change the background color of an item and this works perfectly but when the items are less than the size of the screen.When the items are more and i want to change the background color of an item that is unseeable the app crashes.
Here is some code:

```
 btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setItemRed(v);
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            Cursor data = myDB.getItemID(name);
            int itemID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }
            if(itemID > -1){

                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewElevators.this, ElevatorInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
            }
        }
    });
```

And setItemRed(); :

```
 public void setItemRed(View view) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= myDB.getLastID(); i++) {
        String date = myDB.getcol3(i);
        if (date.equals("null")) {

        } else {
            String day = date.substring(0, 2);
            String dayp = date.substring(0, 1);
            int dayp1 = Integer.parseInt(dayp);
            int day1 = 0;
            if (dayp1 == 0) {
                String dayone = date.substring(1, 2);
                day1 = Integer.parseInt(dayone);
            } else {
                day1 = Integer.parseInt(day);
            }
            String currentDate = currentDate();
            String currentDay = currentDate.substring(0, 2);
            int currentDay1 = Integer.parseInt(currentDay);
            if (date.length() == 10) {
                if (day1 < currentDay1) {
                    listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
```

logcat:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime(3486): 
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
  android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

I read and tried a lot of things but nothing helped.Also, I believe that the problem comes from the screen rotation or that the listview has to store the positions in a boolean for i.e. in case to remember them.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data, you should use `State` to handle this. Anyway, the point here why you are getting this error is that you are getting ID of items in the loop, but items in listView are indexed from 0 and incremented by 1. So you have for example 5 items, so 5th item you can get `listView.getChildAt(4)`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misconception about android `ListView`. They don't actually have single separate views for every items in the list. They contain some fixed amount of views depending upon the height of the `ListView` and they are reused as they are scrolled. So you may get `NullPointerException` on `listView.getChildAt(i)` because there may not be any child for that position.

If you want to change the background color of the list item at certain position, you need to do it inside the `getView` method of your `ListAdapter`.

Comment: This seems logical.So getChildAt() can get positions that are in the screen ration? I will try doing it the other way.Thank you!